# Why does conditional methods must have a return type of void?

Tags: c#, .net, runtime, clr, language-design

We were writing some global exception handler for our API and we need to execute certain method only in `Debug` configuration and obviously conditional method is possible solution.

What I saw however is that `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` can be used only for methods with return type of void as MSDN says:

> A conditional method is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - The conditional method must be a method in a class or struct
>     declaration. A compile-time error occurs if the Conditional attribute
>     is specified on a method in an interface declaration.
> - ***The conditional method must have a return type of void***.
> - The conditional method must not be marked with the override modifier. A conditional method may be marked with the virtual modifier, however. Overrides of such a method are implicitly conditional, and must not be explicitly marked with a Conditional attribute.
> - The conditional method must not be an implementation of an interface method. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622(v=vs.71).aspx

As we know methods marked with `ConditionalAttribute` reach the IL, so why not CLR simply intercept method calls returning `default(T)` for instance therefore allow methods with return type of any type be conditional? Or I am missing something?

Comment: If the method returns something then omitting the call would change the behavior of the code, which is undesirable.  A `void` method has no result local to its call, it can reliably be omitted.

Comment: @David, I don't understand how omitting call to a method that returns something will change the behavior of the code, it will still return something(it will be default(T) for release and actual value for debug), why not?

Comment: @Bathsheba: I see what you're saying, though I wasn't sure if I could really articulate it.  I'd love to get input from the Eric Lipperts of the world on something like this.

Comment: @David: This Eric Lippert's opinion is that your answer is pretty good, though you missed pointing out an important characteristic of void expressions, which I will post in a comment. I'll let the rest of the Eric Lipperts speak for themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why not CLR simply intercept method calls returning `default(T)`

More importantly... why *should* that happen?  If there's no compelling reason to do that, then there's no compelling reason to put in the significant effort, man-hours, cost, etc. to debate it, design it, consider all possible scenarios, develop it, test it, and continue to support it in all future versions of the language.  That's a pretty significant savings for a feature that isn't needed in the first place.

A `void` method is guaranteed to have no result.  So there already exists a logical guarantee that nothing is *relying* on its result.  A method which returns a value can provide no such guarantee.

Since nothing relies on its result, omitting it doesn't change the immediate local behavior of the code/logic.  Whereas if something *did* rely on its result (or at least *might* rely on its result) then local behavior can change, and this is undesirable.  Such a situation could introduce any number of unexpected changes.  Even something as simple as returning `null` where code doesn't expect `null`.

One may be able to personally insist that one may consider their own logic and make their own guarantees outside of what the compiler can guarantee.  (And things like type casting and reflection are probably useful tools to that developer, provided they can maintain the stability they believe they can.)  But in this particular case it *very quickly* becomes a concern that development code and production code are no longer doing the same thing.  They may do very similar things, but no longer the same thing.  This is a significant problem, and the language seeks to avoid that.

It's not about what *can* the system do.  I'm sure there exists an endless variety of things that any given version of any given language *could* support given the information present at that time.  But *should it*?  That's another question entirely.  And in this case it seems that the cost of supporting this would significantly outweigh what one might gain from it.

Comment: Method being void doesnt necessary imply that it will not change behaviour of the code. Often void methods are described as so called "queries" they don't return anything but they can change passed state, so I do not fully agree with you about this part unless you prove me wrong, otherwise about the planing and stuff I expected this kind of answer as everytime I dig why something is not provided by CLR this is the ultimate answer so I am not surprised.

Comment: @kuskmen: A state change and a result are two different things though.  Yes, it may change state elsewhere in the system, such as modifying properties on a supplied object.  Any code can do that.  But locally it is guaranteeing no result and nothing relying on that result.  The compiler in general is less concerned with whether or not business logic exists which can change state and more concerned with whether or not local and structural logic can be guaranteed to work.

Comment: I guess you are right, it is just I don't see how defaulting return type of a function will affect structural logic, maybe I need some elaboration in chat so we don't spam but I see now that you have a point.

Comment: Another nice property of restricting this feature to void methods is that the number of places that such an expression can appear is *extremely limited*, and therefore the number of cases which must be considered and tested is also limited.  An expression of the form `M()` where M is void can only be used in a context where a *statement* is permitted, which means we don't have to worry about cases like `class C { int x = M(); }` -- M() cannot be removed, because it is never legal to have a void expression here in the first place.